# Tool tips on tags (mouseover info) being displayed off-screen

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

When I hover over [steam](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steam) or other tags in the list of my favourite tags, the mouseover popup is shown partially off-screen:

[image: screenshot]

The page fit on-screen before the pop-up, and afterwards a horizontal scrollbar shows up.  I can use my arrow keys to move over (and attempt to keep my mouse above the tag), but that's not ideal behavior.

I use Chrome 11.0.696.57 beta; also occurs in IE 8 and Firefox 4.0 and 4.0.1.  All on Windows XP.

## Edit:

Now it's just the Related Tags, slightly lower on the same sidebar, that exhibit this behavior.  (Favorite and Ignored work properly, as Jin describes in his answer.)

Edit 2: Still happening for related tags.

Comment: Reproduced on IE8 on XP.

Comment: Reproduced on Chrome 11.0.696.57 and Safari 5.0.5, OS X 10.6.7.

Comment: are you on 1024px width resolution?

Comment: @Jin Width is 1050, height is 1680.  (Yes, I'm one of *those* people.)

Comment: @matthew we're looking at some UI tweaks for the fav/ignored tags section. stay tuned.

Comment: [Music](http://music.stackexchange.com) just got "Frequented Tags" ... cool times.

Answer (score 1):

We have disabled the popup from the Favorite/Ignored section on the sidebar. Also we have moved the "X" inside of the tag per [Move the remove tag "X" icon inside the tag in interesting/ignored tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1125/move-the-remove-tag-x-icon-inside-the-tag-in-interesting-ignored-tags)

Comment: The "related tags" just below "ignored tags" still have the pop-up, and suffer the same off-screen issue.  (I don't know if the ignored tags do, since I don't ignore any).